# objective-c none nil array comes up as nil in if/else statement

Tags: iphone, objective-c, if-statement

The following code is not working as expected.  I am setting an array after creating a view but before displaying.  I used NSLog to test that the array is set but the if/else sees the array as empty.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSLog(@"Planlist is nil %d / has %d objects", (planListArr == nil), [planListArr count]);

    if (planListArr == nil || [planListArr count] == 0) { ... }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Planlist is empty");
    }
}
```

Logs

```
2011-09-25 13:54:39.764 myVI[2938:13303] Planlist is nil 0 / has 8 objects
2011-09-25 13:54:39.765 myVI[2938:13303] Planlist is empty
```

PlanList is defined as

```
NSArray *planListArr;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *planListArr;
```

Comment: Can you show the code where your defining the array?  That last bit of code is known as "declaring" the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (planListArr == nil || [planListArr count] == 0) { ... }
else {
    NSLog(@"Planlist is empty");
}
```

Expanded, this becomes:

```
if (planListArr == nil || [planListArr count] == 0) {
    ...
} else {
    NSLog(@"Planlist is empty");
}
```

So basically, it looks like you have your `NSLog()` statement in the wrong branch.

Comment: +This is correct.  The array is NOT empty or nil, so the else gets evald as true, and nslog prints.

Comment: How the NSLog will work for else part "Planlist is empty" if planListArr is nil and its count return 0

Comment: @Praveen-K if the array is `nil` or empty, then `"Planlist is empty"` won't be logged (in the current code).

Comment: sorry, the NSLog should be "Planlist is not empty".

Comment: @DaveDeLong but i still could not figure out how Planlist has 8 objects of **nil** Planlist object

Comment: @sho YES, it should have that message "Plainlist is not empty", but you could have write those if else statment in a single line.

Comment: Sorry, the question was written incorrectly. Yes, the NSLog was in the wrong place.  The first block is correctly skipped with planListArr has 8 object. Thanks everyone!

Comment: I still can bet, that @DaveDeLong answer is still wrong until he do not change the NSLog value "Plainlist is empty" to "Plainlsit is **NOT** empty"

Comment: Whoa why the down votes? My answer is absolutely correct, given the code in the question.

Comment: @DaveDeLong yeah Mr. Dave you are right, *sorry* i initially thought you are giving the right answer rather than pointing him out where is fault.

Answer (score 2):

```
(!plainListArray && [plainListArray count]>0) ? NSLog(@"PlainList array has %d items",[plainListArray count] : NSLog(@"Oops! Array is not been initialized or it has no items");
```